# TypeError: oTable.fnReloadAjax is not a function - DataTables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

i thought i will have no more problems with dataTables as its working now even the refresh.

Turns out some time it works in some places, but in some places it just give this stupid error.

```
TypeError: oTable.fnReloadAjax is not a function
```

Well i have a functon which adds new data in table, after success i want datatable to refresh.

it did work on other view but now As i have created this view, it is not working.

Im using Ignited Datatables.

i have a common.js file includes the datatables script. this script is working fine.

```
function commonDataTables(selector,url,aoColumns){
    var responsiveHelper;
    var breakpointDefinition = {
        tablet: 1024,
        phone : 480
    };
      oTable = selector.dataTable({
        sPaginationType: 'bootstrap',
        oLanguage      : {
            sLengthMenu: '_MENU_ records per page'
        },
        "autoWidth" : false,
        "aoColumns":aoColumns,
        "bServerSide":true,
        "bProcessing":true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": url,
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aLengthMenu": [[2, 25, 50, -1], [2, 25, 50, "All"]],
        'fnServerData'   : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
            $.ajax ({
                'dataType': 'json',
                'type'    : 'POST',
                'url'     : sSource,
                'data'    : aoData,
                'success' : fnCallback
            }); //end of ajax
        },
        'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            $(nRow).attr("data-id",aData[0]);
            responsiveHelper.createExpandIcon(nRow);
            return nRow;
        },
        fnPreDrawCallback: function () {
            // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
            if (!responsiveHelper) {
                responsiveHelper = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper(selector, breakpointDefinition);
            }
        },
        fnDrawCallback : function (oSettings) {
            // Respond to windows resize.
            responsiveHelper.respond();
        }
    });
}
```

Then in my Codeigniter View file.

```
    oTable = '';
    //Data Tables Script Here.
    var selector = $('#ManageTabs');
    var url = "{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/listTabs_DT/";
    var aoColumns =  [
        /* ID */   {
            "bVisible":    false,
            "bSortable":   false,
            "bSearchable": false
        },
        /* Tab Name */  null,
        /* Tab Order */  null,
        /* Tab Desc */  null,
        /* Actions */  null
    ];
    commonDataTables(selector,url,aoColumns);
    //End Of dataTables Script..
```

i am using `oTable` as global variable so defined the `oTable` outside the document.ready function

```
var oTable;
```

i know its a bad practice to use global variable but i wanted to find a work around to make the datatable refresh all the data.

Well this global variable Method did worked out for 1 view but in this next view i get the error which i told you already.

Here, below is the code of the button where in success it should have performed its duty but instead it gave error..

```
            $('#createTabBtn').on('click', function(e){
                //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                var selector = $('#createTabModelForm');
                HRS.formValidation(selector);
                if(selector.valid()){
                    var formData = {
                        TabName : $("#cTabName").val(),
                        TabOrder : $("#cTabOrder").val(),
                        TabDesc :   $("#cTabDesc").val()
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/addNewTab/",
                        dataType:"json",
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(output){
                            if (output == true){
                                oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    //Do Stuff After pressing the Create Button.
//                    Close the Modal
                    $('#addNewTabModal_ManageTabs').modal('hide');
//                    Reset All the TextBoxes and CheckBoxes
                    $("#createTabModelForm")[0].reset();
//                    Reset/Empty All the Select2 Dropdowns
                    //jQuery('.select2-offscreen').select2('val', '');
                }
                else{
                    //The Else Portion if you want Something else to Happen if not validated Form
                }

            });
```

Please can anyone know the best way to refresh the dataTables..

Comment: destroy and recreate the table was the solution once to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG, i forgot to add the `fnReloadAjax.js` file. i added that in first view but forgot to add in this view..

so anyone if face any problem like this, just see if the js file is attached.

being careless cost me my time but eventually problem solved.

But still there is a issue of Global Variable i mean i use global variable to refresh the grid.

if anyone has better option to use this `fnreloadajax` function. plz share.

Comment: I made the same mistake.